# SQL simple case statement with formula

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried adding in a THEN after the WHEN but don't know how to just make it show up as the result of the formula

```
CASE
WHEN (PLANAVAILDATE - CURRENT_DATE) =>280
ELSE ''
END AS Days Overdue
```

Comment: Firstly its a case *expression* (not a *statement*) - which might be your issue, because it can only return a scalar value (not that we know what you are trying to return. Secondly you want the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: And `=>` should be `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a case statement for this you can directly count the days of overdue
by using this

`DATEDIFF(hour, PLANAVAILDATE, CURRENT_DATE)/24 AS 'Days Overdue'`

if you can provide the full question I will give you exact solution

Comment: i need to add a column with this formula that will work within my main query: where(planavaildate - current_date) >=280 and the result has to show up in days and (the 280 in the formula is referring to 280 days)

Comment: Current date and planvalidate are int values or timestamp?

Comment: Can you provide us the full question